# How to add a collection inside document on Firestore? React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

```
async componentDidMount() {

    firebase.firestore().collection('profiles').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {

        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

            var data = doc.data().pushToken; // I'm able to fetch pushToken here.

            const profileRef = firebase.firestore.doc(`profiles/0bT9eZ42CNN1uQYAE728WJht2aO2`)
                .collection('private').doc('pushToken');

            profileRef.set(data, {
                merge: true
            }).catch(e => console.error(e));

        });

    })
    .catch(function(error) {

        alert("error"); // My .then function throws an error and hence this alert works

        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });

}
```

I want to be able to fetch `pushToken` from each document's field and then insert into a collection within the same document by the name `private`.
But it gives me an error saying

> Error getting documents:  TypeError:
>   _reactNativeFirebase2.default.firestore.doc is not a function

How can I move `pushToken` to a collection? And I want to make the collection inside each document automatically and not manually.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) for the document that you want to create a subcollection under, you can build the `CollectionReference` and `DocumentReference` to the new document from that.

Something like this should work:

```
const profileRef = doc.ref.collection('private').doc('pushToken');
```

Comment: can you please check my updated question now. I've now replied to the answer. :)